# How to unwrap nested functions with javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello everyone on my angular controller I have the following methods:

```
$scope.scanSuccess = function(result) {
                    alert("We got a barcode\n" +
                            "Result: " + result.text + "\n" +
                            "Format: " + result.format + "\n" +
                            "Cancelled: " + result.cancelled);
                };

$scope.scanSuccessW = function(){
  return $scope.scanSuccess;
}
```

Is there any way to get scanSuccess starting from scanSuccessW? When I write something like this:

```
var s = $scope.scanSuccessW;
```

s always refers to the scanSuccessW (the wrapper) and not to the wrapped method; is there any way to unwrap a function on javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute the function, instead of getting a reference to it, because it returns the `$scope.scanSuccess` function.

```
var s = $scope.scanSuccessW();
//                         ^^ use parenthesis to execute it
```